# casting shadow on invisible plane in Scenekit / ARkit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

Im finding difficult to caste a shadow on invisible plane in scenekit , firstly I am trying to create an invisible plane under my AR Object and casting shadow on it , so far failed to do both

One thing Im doing right is that my object has the shadow on other AR object but not on ground (because I think Im unable to create the invisible plane on which shadow will be casted)

Note : Im using apple's demo project code for my project

Kindly Help , Thanks in advance

**didAdd node delegate**

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.statusViewController.cancelScheduledMessage(for: .planeEstimation)
        self.statusViewController.showMessage("SURFACE DETECTED")
        if self.virtualObjectLoader.loadedObjects.isEmpty {
            self.statusViewController.scheduleMessage("TAP ON SCREEN TO PLACE AN OBJECT", inSeconds: 7.5, messageType: .contentPlacement)
        }
    }
    updateQueue.async {
        for object in self.virtualObjectLoader.loadedObjects {
            object.adjustOntoPlaneAnchor(planeAnchor, using: node)
        }
    }
}
```

**didUpdate node delegate**

```
   func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor ,
          let planeNode = node.childNodes.first,let plane = planeNode.geometry as? SCNPlane else { return }
     
    // 2
    let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
    let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
    plane.width = width
    plane.height = height
     
    // 3
    let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
    let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
    let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
    updateQueue.async {
        for object in self.virtualObjectLoader.loadedObjects {
            object.adjustOntoPlaneAnchor(planeAnchor, using: node)
        }
    }
}
```

**casting shadow on other object**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like so:

The plane for the shadows:

```
func shadowPlane() -> SCNNode {

    let objectShape                    = SCNPlane(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
    objectShape.heightSegmentCount     = 1
    objectShape.widthSegmentCount      = 1

    let objectNode                     = SCNNode(geometry: objectShape)
    objectNode.renderingOrder          = -10 // for Shadow Material Standard
    objectNode.position                = yourPosition
    objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = shadowMaterialStandard()
    objectNode.castsShadow             = false // Important
    objectNode.eulerAngles             = SCNVector3(CGFloat.pi/2, 0.0, 0.0)
    objectNode.name                    = "floor"

    return objectNode
}
```

For the Material:

```
func shadowMaterialStandard() -> SCNMaterial {
    
    let material                  = SCNMaterial()
    
    material.colorBufferWriteMask = SCNColorMask(rawValue: 0) // important
    material.diffuse.contents     = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    material.lightingModel        = .physicallyBased // OK
    material.isDoubleSided        = true
    
    return material
}
```

For the Lighting:

```
func directionalLight() -> SCNLight {
    
    let light                           = SCNLight()
    light.type                          = .directional
    light.castsShadow                   = true
    light.color                         = UIColor.white
    light.shadowColor                   = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.75)
    light.shadowMode                    = .deferred
    light.shadowRadius                  = 2.0  // 3.25 // suggestion by StackOverflow
    light.shadowCascadeCount            = 3    // suggestion by StackOverflow
    light.shadowCascadeSplittingFactor  = 0.09 // suggestion by StackOverflow
    light.shadowBias                    = 0.1  // what's this?
    light.shadowSampleCount             = 8    // Quality of the Shadow - impacts performance when to high
    light.categoryBitMask               = -1   // Shine on Everything

    return light
}

func ambientLight() -> SCNLight {

    let light               = SCNLight()
    light.type              = .ambient
    light.color             = UIColor.white
    light.intensity         = 250
    light.categoryBitMask   = -1 // Shine on Everything

    return light
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy <3 , gonna try it and then will let you know if it works

Comment: how to add light in the scene ? just like adding to rootnode as we add other nodes ?

Comment: yeah, add the SCNLight to a SCNNode's .light property - that's it.

Comment: it doesn't casting any shadow on the ground and sometime it invisible the the half AR object .... :( ... can you please tell me the appropriate way to add the plane and light to the scene ... how to handle addNode and updateNode delegate ? i might me doing something wrong there :(

Comment: how can i share , tell me ? should i add you to github contributor ?

Comment: give me your github username

Comment: you seems like a champion in ARKit ... may i have any of your contact number or anything from which i can connect to you ?

Comment: its uploading on g-drive which is taking so much time ... once its done will definitely give you the link